# html 5 - to offer full clipboard control? (for discussion)

Tags: html

I get it. Security becomes an issue with allowing a website to Paste content onto a users clipboard. I have yet to find a reliable way to do that, that doesn't involve on the subject-to-change per the current version, soon-to-stop-working Flash way of doing it.

Perfect world: the 1st time a website tries to use a user's clipboard, prompt him or her with "site ABC wants to copy content on your clipboard, do you want to allow?" with "always trust ABC" as a checkbox, would be great. Best of both worlds.

Summary question for discussion: will html 5 make it easier to utilize the users' clipboard?

Comment: Of all the things HTML5 *could* introduce, this probably won't be one of them. I mean, fundamentally, shouldn't clipboard control be a behavior and thus a job for Javascript instead?

Comment: Oh, would that HTML 5 be a markup language; it isn't (at least, not *just* a markup language). It defines a vast collection of APIs designed for JS interaction, so this question isn't as odd as Yi suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML5 spec currently contains [one mention of the word 'clipboard'](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#common-event-behaviors) and that is in relation to `change` events so: **Probably not**.

Comment: Bummer!! oh well. maybe someone really smart can come up with a way that will always work.